# Bitmap to Metal Texture and back - How does the pixelFormat work?

Tags: swift, macos, metal

I'm having problems understanding how the pixelFormat of a MTLTexture relates to the properties of a NSBitmapImageRep?

In particular, I want to use a metal compute kernel (or the built in MPS method) to subtract an image from another one and KEEP the negative values temporarily.

I have a method that creates a MTLTexture from a bitmap with a specified pixelFormat:

```
func textureFrom(bitmap: NSBitmapImageRep, pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat) -> MTLTexture? {

    guard !bitmap.isPlanar else {
        return nil
    }

    let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, bitmap.pixelsWide, bitmap.pixelsHigh)

    var textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
    textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: pixelFormat, width: bitmap.pixelsWide, height: bitmap.pixelsHigh, mipmapped: false)

    guard let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor),
        let src = bitmap.bitmapData else { return nil }

    texture.replace(region: region, mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: src, bytesPerRow: bitmap.bytesPerRow)
    return texture
}
```

Then I use the textures to do some computation (like a subtraction) and when I'm done, I want to get a bitmap back. In the case of textures with a .r8Snorm pixelFormat, I thought I could do:

```
func bitmapFrom(r8SnormTexture: MTLTexture?) -> NSBitmapImageRep? {

    guard let texture = r8SnormTexture,
        texture.pixelFormat == .r8Snorm else { return nil }

    let bytesPerPixel = 1
    let imageByteCount = Int(texture.width * texture.height * bytesPerPixel)
    let bytesPerRow = texture.width * bytesPerPixel
    var src = [Float](repeating: 0, count: imageByteCount)

    let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height)
    texture.getBytes(&src, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let context = CGContext(data: &src, width: texture.width, height: texture.height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    guard let dstImageFilter = context?.makeImage() else {
        return nil
    }

    return NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: dstImageFilter)
}
```

But the negative values are not preserved, they are clamped to zero somehow...

Any insight on how swift goes from bitmap to texture and back would be appreciated.

Comment: `norm` formats map the range of their values to the range [0,1], which means that negative values will be clamped to 0 before being written to an `r8Snorm` texture. You'll need to manually scale/bias the data or use a floating-point format to preserve negative values.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. However, I am wondering what the "S" in r8Snorm means if not that it is signed? And if it is signed, where is the sign?

Comment: I'm sorry for the error; you're right that an `Snorm` texture is signed. The range in that case is [-1,1], corresponding to the values [-32767.0, 32767.0].